# If the CSSRule.type property is deprecated what can I used instead

Tags: css, dom

The [CSSRule docs in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSRule/type) states that the `CSSRule.type` property is deprecated and is not clear to me what should be used instead if one wants to check the type of `CSSRule`. Adding some code for reference.

```js
const isStyleOrImportRule = (rule: CSSRule): boolean => {
  // 1 -> CSSRule.STYLE_RULE
  // 3 -> CSSRule.IMPORT_RULE   
  return  [1,3].includes(rule.type)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a better way to do this and avoiding deprecation issues referencing the constructor function name.

```js
const isStyleOrImportRule = (rule: CSSRule): boolean => {
  return ['CSSStyleRule', 'CSSImportRule'].includes(rule.constructor.name)
}
```